# Easier way of dealing with CurrentValueSubject

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `Complex` `class` which I pass around as an `EnvironmentObject` through my SwiftUI views. `Complex` contains several `CurrentValueSubject`s. I don't want to add the `Published` attribute to the publishers on `class` `Complex`, since `Complex` is used a lot around the views and that will force the views to reload on every published value.

Instead, I want a mechanism which can subscribe to specific publisher which `Complex` holds. That way, `View`s can choose on which publisher the view should re-render itself.

The code below works, but I was wondering if there was an easier solution, it feels like a lot of work just to listen to the updates `CurrentValueSubject` gives me:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    let complex = Complex()
    
    var body: some View {
        PublisherView(boolPublisher: .init(publisher: complex.boolPublisher))
        .environmentObject(complex)
    }
}

struct PublisherView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var complex: Complex
    @ObservedObject var boolPublisher: BoolPublisher
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(String(describing: boolPublisher.publisher))")
    }
}

class Complex: ObservableObject {
    let boolPublisher: CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never> = .init(true)
    
    // A lot more...
    
    init() {
        startToggling()
    }
    
    func startToggling() {
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [unowned self] in
            let newValue = !boolPublisher.value
            
            print("toggling to \(newValue)")
            
            boolPublisher.send(newValue)
            
            startToggling()
        }
    }
}

class BoolPublisher: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellableBag: AnyCancellable? = nil
    @Published var publisher: Bool
    
    init(publisher: CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>) {
        self.publisher = publisher.value
        
        cancellableBag = publisher
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] value in
                self?.publisher = value
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't say `@Published` and you don't say `objectWillChange`, in what sense is Complex an ObservableObject at all? You might as well delete that term entirely. It's just an object.

Comment: @matt I want to pass `Complex` around as an `@EnvironmentObject`, that's why it conforms to `ObservableObject`. I could pass it around in initializers, but that doesn't really change the question.